# PHP customized checkout open source

Tags: php, open-source, checkout

I have searched around but couldn't find an open source checkout that allows serious single product customization. I have a single product website I've built and simply would like to integrate a cart / checkout to my "Add to Cart" Button on my product page. The product comes in different sizes and colors so the cart must treat each product as a separate entity in the cart. I have some experience with PHP, JS, and SQL - can anyone recommend a game plan here?

Comment: [magento community edition](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download)?

Comment: Thanks Eikeki - Is there anything out there that is just source code for a Cart and checkout system? Magento seems like a full on package  - for a storefront selling hundreds of products.

Comment: It seems like it's a fairly large commitment learning the complex structure of Magento just to integrate the cart and checkout like I need.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes Free single page Checkout is now available in Magento connect,
>   Swift Checkout
>   http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/19525/